# Заполнение массивов и вставка данных из них в таблицу

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

У меня есть задача написать программу, которая генерирует скрипт на PL/SQL на добавление записей в таблицу. Скрипт и программу написала, но корректно оно будет работать только для одной записи.

Например, у меня есть структура, в которой содержатся параметры сбора данных из разных таблиц. Скрипт их ищет и вставляет в целевую таблицу.

Я хочу, чтобы скрипт мог работать с массивом таких структур.
В какую сторону лучше искать решение или где можно найти пример?

Прав на создание новых таблиц нет. Есть только возможность делать insert в эти две таблицы.

```
DECLARE
    objid NUMBER;
    part NUMBER;
    territory NUMBER;
    lvl3 NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT obj_num INTO objid FROM sa.adp_tbl_oid WHERE type_id = (SELECT o.type_id FROM sa.adp_object o WHERE o.type_name = 'x_c_wfm_map') FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE sa.adp_tbl_oid SET obj_num = objid + 1
WHERE type_id = (SELECT o.type_id FROM sa.adp_object o WHERE o.type_name = 'x_c_wfm_map');
SELECT terr.OBJID INTO territory FROM TABLE_TERRITORY terr WHERE terr.TERR_ID = 'SIB';

SELECT pn.OBJID INTO part FROM TABLE_PART_NUM pn WHERE pn.PART_NUMBER = 'Интернет по Ethernet' AND pn.FAMILY <> 'ККФУ';

SELECT type3.objid INTO lvl3 FROM table_hgbst_lst list
INNER JOIN table_hgbst_show show1 ON show1.objid = list.hgbst_lst2hgbst_show
INNER JOIN mtm_hgbst_elm0_hgbst_show1 m1 ON show1.objid = m1.hgbst_show2hgbst_elm
INNER JOIN table_hgbst_elm type1 ON type1.objid = m1.hgbst_elm2hgbst_show AND type1.state != 'Inactive'
INNER JOIN mtm_hgbst_elm0_hgbst_show1 m2 ON type1.objid = m2.hgbst_elm2hgbst_show
INNER JOIN table_hgbst_show show2 ON show2.objid = m2.hgbst_show2hgbst_elm AND show2.objid != show1.objid
INNER JOIN mtm_hgbst_elm0_hgbst_show1 m3 ON show2.objid = m3.hgbst_show2hgbst_elm 
INNER JOIN table_hgbst_elm type2 ON type2.objid = m3.hgbst_elm2hgbst_show AND type2.objid != type1.objid AND type2.state != 'Inactive'
INNER JOIN mtm_hgbst_elm0_hgbst_show1 m4 ON type2.objid = m4.hgbst_elm2hgbst_show
INNER JOIN table_hgbst_show show3 ON show3.objid = m4.hgbst_show2hgbst_elm AND show3.objid = m4.hgbst_show2hgbst_elm AND show3.objid != show2.objid
INNER JOIN mtm_hgbst_elm0_hgbst_show1 m5 ON show3.objid = m5.hgbst_show2hgbst_elm
INNER JOIN table_hgbst_elm type3 ON type3.objid = m5.hgbst_elm2hgbst_show AND type3.objid != type2.objid AND type3.state != 'Inactive'
WHERE list.title = 'CASE_TYPE' AND type1.title = 'Техподдержка' AND type2.title = 'Сервис.обслуж-е клиентского оборудования' AND type3.title = 'Подключение клиентского оборудования';

INSERT ALL
INTO sa.TABLE_X_C_WFM_MAP 
(OBJID, DEV, X_IS_ACTIVE, X_TECH_FAMILY, X_C_WFM_MAP2C_TYPE_LVL3, X_C_WFM_MAP2TERRITORY, X_C_WFM_MAP2PART_NUM)
VALUES
(objid + 1, 1, 1, 'FTTx', lvl3, territory, part)
SELECT * FROM dual;
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: 1) "которая генерирует скрипт на pl sql на добавление записей в таблицу"- приведённый код генерированный? 2) "но корректно оно будет работать только для одной записи" - если вы вставляетеодну одну запись, то коректно может быть вставленна одна запись.  3) "Прав на создание новых таблиц нет" - они вам нужны? Короче - ничего не понятно.

Comment: @0xdb Приведённый запрос - сгенерированный, на вход ему передан массив из одной записи, в которой перечислены условия, вставляемые в запрос:
PART_NUMBER = 'Интернет по Ethernet'
TERR_ID = 'SIB'
type1 = 'Техподдержка' 
type2 = 'Сервис.обслуж-е клиентского оборудования' 
type3 = 'Подключение клиентского оборудования'
family = 'FTTx'.
Мне нужно, чтобы без увеличения количества запросов в теле скрипта (например,условия через OR) вытаскивать нужные данные в массив

Comment: @0xdb Проблема в том, что я в принципе не знаю, реализуемо ли такое.

Comment: Пока не совсем понял, что вы пытаетесь реализовать.  "вытаскивать нужные данные в массив" - да возможно:  `select ... bulk collect into <массив>`; потом вставка с `forall index in <массив>...  insert ...`, а не с `insert all ... `.

Comment: Автору вопроса - [советую ознакомиться](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall) - это старый, но все ещё актуальный блог...

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте сгенерировать блок на основе этого воиспроизодимого примера:

```
create table src as
    select rownum objid, cast ('memo '||rownum as varchar2 (64)) memo from xmlTable ('1 to 5');
create table tgt (id number, memo varchar2 (64));

declare 
    type rowType is record (id number, memo varchar2 (64)); 
    type arrType is table of rowType; 
    arr arrType;
begin
    select objid, memo bulk collect into arr
    from src 
    where objid in (1,3,5)
    ;
    forall idx in 1..arr.count
    insert into tgt values (arr (idx).id, arr (idx).memo)
    ;
end;
/
commit;

select * from tgt;

        ID MEMO                                                           
---------- ----------------
         1 memo 1                                                          
         3 memo 3                                                          
         5 memo 5
```

Подробнее о *bulk processing* можно ознакомится в [этой статье в *Oracle Magazine*](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/bulk-processing-with-bulk-collect-and-forall) любезно предоставленной @MaxU, или, как обычно, в офф. документации: [тык тут](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/returninginto_clause.htm#GUID-38F735B9-1100-45AF-AE71-18FB74A899BE__CJAIAGHJ) и [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321).

Answer (score 3):

Помимо стандартного решения с  `bulk collect ... forall` конструкцией, для задачи поставленной в вопросе возможно лучше подойдёт следующее решение.

Подготовка схемы, влючая вспомогательную функцию (статическая, то есть не требует генерации):

```
create table src as
    select rownum objid, cast ('memo '||rownum as varchar2 (64)) memo from xmlTable ('1 to 5');
create table tgt (id number, memo varchar2 (64));

create or replace type rowType as object (id number, memo varchar2 (64)); 
/
create or replace type arrType is table of rowType;
/

create or replace function pipedResultSet (cur sys_refcursor) return arrType pipelined is
    arr arrType;
begin
    loop 
        fetch cur bulk collect into arr limit 5000;
        exit when arr.count = 0; 
        for idx in 1..arr.count loop pipe row (arr (idx)); end loop;
    end loop; 
    return;
end;
/
```

Далее, блок который может/должен быть сгенерирован:

```
variable mycur refcursor 
begin 
    open :mycur for 
        --## begin generated code
        select rowType (objid, memo) 
        from src 
        where objid in (1,3,5)
        ;
        --## end generated code

end;
/
```

В заключении, собственно вставка:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited 
begin 
    insert all
    into tgt values (id, memo)
    select id, memo
    from table (pipedResultSet (:mycur)) 
    ;
    dbms_output.put_line (sql%rowcount||' row(s) inserted.'); 
end;
/

3 row(s) inserted.
```

Вывод:

```
SQL>    select * from tgt;

        ID MEMO
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
         1 memo 1
         3 memo 3
         5 memo 5
```

PS Если объём данных внушителен, то возможно с предикатом `PARALLEL_ENABLE` и *Direct-Path* записью добится значительного прироста производительности, то есть *performance booster* (пер. авт.: ну просто чума).